# Pandas: Multiple indices in a dataframe: drop some, keep others

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

My data has the following structure:

```
>>> df.head()
                                   value
Date       FIPS_state Date              
2001-01-01 1          2001-03-31  6.4621
           2          2001-03-31 11.3259
           4          2001-03-31  6.3467
           5          2001-03-31  6.0613
           6          2001-03-31  7.5069
```

[I'd like to post this dataframe here for convenience, but I can't even figure that out now. However see `data` and the steps outlined further down to recreate it.]

The desired output is:

```
>>> df.head()                                   
   FIPS_state Date        value      
0  1          2001-03-31  6.4621
1  2          2001-03-31 11.3259
2  4          2001-03-31  6.3467
3  5          2001-03-31  6.0613
4  6          2001-03-31  7.5069
```

where I want to drop the first `Date` index but keep the second `Date` index, and also have the `FIPS_state` index as a variable.

Maybe I shouldn't be here in the first place. The `Date` index was created while running the following:

```
import pandas
from pandas import Timestamp

data = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({'FIPS_state': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 'FIPS_county': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3}, 'value': {0: 3.1, 1: 3.4, 2: 3.9, 3: 5.9, 4: 6.4}, 'Date': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2020-11-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-09-01 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00')}, 'Month/Year': {0: '12/2020', 1: '11/2020', 2: '10/2020', 3: '9/2020', 4: '8/2020'}})

df = data.set_index('Date').groupby(['Date','FIPS_state']).resample('Q')['value'].mean().to_frame()

>>> df.head()
#   FIPS_state FIPS_county  value       Date Month/Year
# 0          1           3 3.1000 2020-12-01    12/2020
# 1          1           3 3.4000 2020-11-01    11/2020
# 2          1           3 3.9000 2020-10-01    10/2020
# 3          1           3 5.9000 2020-09-01     9/2020
# 4          1           3 6.4000 2020-08-01     8/2020
```

**EDIT:** This is not even doing the correct calculation, is it? Oh my... Anyways, my question about the index has been answered below by @user17242583, thanks!

Comment: I have made several attempts involving `.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)` and `.rename_axis(None)`, but I daresay I don't have a good understanding of these indices.

Comment: Your out put dose not do anything to your df , it is same

Comment: I noticed that too...

Comment: @BENY and user: Looks like I messed up at the point of resampling the data, right?

Comment: @PatrickT yes , I thing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by removing the the first `Date` column from the index (or any `Date` column - there just shouldn't be duplicate column names):

```py
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
```

Then reset the index:

```py
df = df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
   FIPS_state        Date    value
0           1  2001-03-31   6.4621
1           2  2001-03-31  11.3259
2           4  2001-03-31   6.3467
3           5  2001-03-31   6.0613
4           6  2001-03-31   7.5069
```

Comment: pure magic! Thanks! Do you know how I should implement the `resample('Q')` step to avoid this issue in the first place?

Comment: the duplicate is in the index or does it get in the column names too at some point when piping methods while resampling?

Comment: Hmm...knowing little about `resample()` I can't give much advice. I'm not sure why the `Date` column gets duplicated. For sure though, it's getting duplicate _in the index_.

Comment: Using `groupby` always creates a new dataframe where the index is the column(s) you grouped by, so the MultiIndex with FPS_state and Date are because you specified those columns in your groupby.

Comment: You call `mean()` which just returns a series...where the index is that multiindex, so maybe you could drop the whole index of the Series and assign it directly to the df like this? `df['val'] = df.set_index('Date').groupby(['Date','FIPS_state']).resample('Q')['value'].mean().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Anyway, this should likely go in its own question.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you need

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='Q'), 'FIPS_state'])['value'].mean().reset_index()

        Date  FIPS_state     value
0 2020-09-30           1  6.150000
1 2020-12-31           1  3.466667
```

Comment: Thanks @BENY ! A minute ago I accepted the other answer, but yours is very timely and ultimately it's what I needed to fix. I had tried to use `pandas.Grouper` before, but hadn't managed to understand it (in the limited time and effort available). This is so helpful! Btw I've learned so much from the many answers you have on pandas dataframes. Great contributions!

Comment: You're a good pandas teach too @PatrickT. :) Before this question, I didn't know how easy it was to convert a MultiIndex into normal columns :D